# How to get firebase analytics events without using bigQuery in laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-analytics

How do I get Firebase Analytics Events in my Laravel application? And without using BigQuery how to get events in my Laravel application.

I tried `kreait/firebase-php` and `kreait/laravel-firebase` packages but these packages are not working for me.

Comment: It's quite well documented by now that the way to get the raw analytics events out of Google Analytics is through Firebase's BigQuery export for it. Why don't you want to use that approach?

Comment: because of only purchased account get records and i don't have subscription

Comment: There is a no-cost sandbox in BigQuery for projects on the free plan. https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export#pricing